# What is a safe heap size?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have created a simple game with libgdx. It's currently showing about 50mb heap size. I believe everything is being disposed, and I try not to create objects in redner loop. What is a safe heap size?

Answer (score 0):

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)

> ...each Android-powered device has a different amount of RAM available to the system and thus provides a different heap limit for each app. You can call getMemoryClass() to get an estimate of your app's available heap in megabytes. If your app tries to allocate more memory than is available here, it will receive an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: The weird thing is that from looking android monitor, I use 50mb. That seems to pass the max heap for alot of devicecs.